# running peerjs server in the background forever

Tags: javascript, node.js, forever, peer

I have installed my peerjs server on my remote server. I can login to my server through putty SSH. I can run the server but when I close the putty it ends the session and peerjs stops. How can I make it run forever in the server.

I have tried forever package like this.

```
forever start peerjs --port 9000 --key peerjs
```

But geting this error.

```
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: peerjs
error:   Cannot start forever
error:   script /root/peerjs does not exist.
```

Comment: Try forever start `/abs/path/to/peerjs` --port 9000 --key peerjs

Comment: both peerjs and forever are installed in the same directory.

Comment: Did you try with a `sudo` at the beginning of the command?

Comment: yes. giving same error

Answer (score 2):

The problem is solved by creating a custom server by just adding these two lines

```
var PeerServer = require('peer').PeerServer;
var server = PeerServer({port: 9000, path: '/peerjs'});
```

to the `node_modules/peer/node_modules/we/index.js` file
then running the server with

```
forever start node_modules/peer/node_modules/we/index.js
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run (start) peer server from code:

> ```
> var PeerServer = require('peer').PeerServer;
> var server = PeerServer({port: 443, path: '/peerjs'});
> ```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply add the keyword "&" after your peerjs command it will keep on running in background in putty.

example.  peerjs --port 3001 &

Answer (score -1):

Close your browser tab where video transfer or audio transfer is on.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).